# why elements of python dictionary not get printed in sequence

Tags: python, dictionary

i have this dictionary

```
sr = {'DTW':'CNT','FWA':'CNT','GRR':'CNT','IND':'CNT','MKE':'CNT','MLI':'CNT','MSP':'CNT','OMA':'CNT','ORD':'CNT','SBN':'CNT','STL':'CNT','BDL':'EST','BOS':'EST','BWI':'EST','CLE':'EST','CMH':'EST','CVG':'EST','EWR':'EST','IAD':'EST','JFK':'EST','MDT':'EST','PHL':'EST','PIT':'EST','ROC':'EST','ABQ':'CNT','AUS':'CNT','DEN':'CNT','DFW':'CNT','ELP':'CNT','IAH':'CNT','LRD':'CNT','MCI':'CNT','MFE':'CNT','MSY':'CNT','OKC':'CNT','SAT':'CNT','TUL':'CNT','ATL':'EST','BNA':'EST','CLT':'EST','JAX':'EST','MCO':'EST','MEM':'EST','MIA':'EST','RDU':'EST','RIC':'EST','SDF':'EST','SJU':'EST','TPA':'EST','ANC':'WST','HNL':'WST','LAS':'WST','LAX':'WST','PDX':'WST','PHX':'WST','RNO':'WST','SAN':'WST','SEA':'WST','SFO':'WST','SLC':'WST','SMF':'WST','TUS':'WST'}

for s, r in sr.iteritems():
   print s, r
```

but while printing it is printing starting with

```
JFK EST
MKE CNT
```

why? why printing is not staring with DTW?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for a dictionary?  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items  Seems pretty clear.  What part about this confused you?  Can you provide a quote or a link that was confusing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the implementation of a dict is a hashmap or [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), wich doesn't store the elements in order.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict)

> CPython implementation detail: Keys
>   and values are listed in an arbitrary
>   order which is non-random, varies
>   across Python implementations, and
>   depends on the dictionary’s history of
>   insertions and deletions.

If the order is important, you should use the [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1):

[PyMOTO OrderedDict](http://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html) tutorial provides good examples about [OrderedDict()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this has changed since Python 3.7

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict - "Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6."